# "Your request included an invalid SAML response" in integrating Azure AD and AWS

Tags: php, azure, amazon-web-services

Followed the steps outlined in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-saas-amazon-web-service-tutorial and as Dirk_Nelson points out in the comments:

> Error: Your request included an invalid SAML response. To logout,
>   click here.
>
> After digging around AWS' documentation, I found this article:
>   http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/troubleshoot_saml.html#troubleshoot_saml_invalid-response
>
> 1. Attribute Name rolesessionname changed to RoleSessionName
> 2. Attribute Name role changed to Role
> 3. Namespace needs to be https://aws.amazon.com/SAML/Attributes for BOTH RoleSessionName and Role
>
> After making those changes in the Azure portal I was able to
>   successfully authenticate.

Though I already had this. Alternatively, the Amazon troubleshooting page says this is due to the Role lacking attribute values with the ARN.

```
<AttributeValue>arn:aws:iam::account-number:role/role-name1,arn:aws:iam::account-number:saml-provider/provider-name</AttributeValue>
```

I tried this as well, but no luck. Is there anything else that could be missing?

End goal is to login through **Amazon Cognito** with users stored in **Azure AD**, and this seems to be a solution unless I'm interpreting this as the opposite route of what I need.

Comment: Looks like missing attributes in SAML response. Hard to debug without a sample SAML response.

Comment: Note that SAML response may contain sensitive data; remove it before posting if u choose to do so.

Comment: Seems like I needed to bind a role in Azure AD to a user (I couldn't get groups working for some reason). I can now successfully go from myapps.microsoft.com to AWS, but what about the reverse? When I'm in AWS I copied the IAM users sign-in link but it doesn't work. Do I need to setup user provision in order for this to work?

Comment: What do you mean reverse? You mean u are trying to login using Azure users using the AWS IAM link? That won't work.

Comment: Yeah my web app used Cognito which hooks into Aws IAM but I want to also be able to authenticate Azure Ad users through that.

Comment: You can't authenticate Azure users through Aws Iam link. You need to write your own code for that using Cognito with Azure as a Saml provider

Comment: @agent420 - thanks - went the simplesaml route and hooked it up to azure. is there a straightforward way to bypass having an external login and just do it through my web app directly?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158165/discussion-between-meder-omuraliev-and-agent420).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***To sum up the above discussion*:**

- Invalid SAML response was due to missing attribute (Role) in SAML response

**Use Case**

- Implement authentication in PHP application using Azure AD using a custom UI

**Solutions explored**

- Integrate Azure AD with Cognito as a SAML IdP
- Integrate Azure AD with Cognito as an OIDC Provider
- Use Azure AD directly in your app as an [OIDC provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-code)
- Skip AWS integration altogether & use custom libraries

**Issue**

- All the above solutions redirect to Microsoft login page

**Next steps**

- Skip AWS integration, for sure
- Using default Azure login UI would have the simplest solution but not viable
- Look for some PHP library which can be used to do the same. Most IdPs like Cognito, Auth0 tec. provide SDKs which can be used to get tokens pragmatically using Username & Password i.e. one can implement his own login UI & extract username, password & use it in the SDK methods. Check if it is possible with [Azure SDKs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-authentication-libraries)
- Possible solution with [this](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer2) library but untested and not in PHP.